# Fectching Decimal values from XLS using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to Fetch Decimal value from a excel sheet using vbscript

The function I am using is:

```
Abc=objExcel.Cells(RowNo,ColNo).Value
```

When cell value=12.45 results in  Abc=12.45 which is correct

but when cell value=12.00 results in Abc=12 whereas I need Abc to be 12.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about formatting after getting the value:

```
' VBA
Format(Abc, "0.00")
```

Or

```
' Vbscript
Abc = objExcel.Cells(RowNo,ColNo).Value 
Abc = FormatNumber(Abc, 2)
```

Comment: Formatting is not an option for me.

Comment: What about `FormatNumber(Abc=objExcel.Cells(RowNo,ColNo).Value, 2)` ?

Comment: What you're modifying in the code i posted is the variable, and not the Excel cell's value, so that should be fine. If your concern is the presentation of data in Excel before anything, then you can just format the column in Excel's GUI.